# Graphics changing alignment in second vbox

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, plain-tex, optex

I am trying to top-align text next to a bare image in PlainTeX/OpTeX, using the idiom:

```
\hbox to \hsize {
    \vtop{\hsize=... ...}
    \hskip...
    \vtop{\hsize=... ...}}
```

And this seems to work well if both of the vboxes contain text, but if I use \inspic (or \includegraphics), then the alignment gets thrown off drastically and the second box gets its baseline (forgive me if the term is incorrect) shifted down all the way to the bottom of the image.

Could someone please elaborate on what the image could be doing that is shifting the other box like this and what could be done to prevent it?

EDIT: Apologies, adding example of exactly what I mean.

```
\input lua-visual-debug.sty
\input graphicx.tex %

\hbox to \hsize {
    % \vtop{\hsize=0.54\hsize \indent \includegraphics[width=8.5cm]{sunrise.jpg}}

     \vtop{\hsize=0.4\hsize
Non impedit maxime sed expedita. Ab harum sit numquam molestiae minima nostrum quia. Dolores voluptatem rerum voluptatibus nihil maiores non. Provident perferendis eligendi nihil deleniti sunt qui cum dolore. Recusandae quos a ipsa dolorem.…
 }

    \hskip4mm
    \vtop{\hsize=0.4\hsize
    Omnis voluptatem rem dolores ex. In rerum autem ut. Fugiat non in dolorum minima accusantium aperiam nobis aliquam.
}}

\bye
```

These two are the outputs of the code above and (un)commenting the other vtop

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be easier to test if you showed an actual example (you could use `example-image`)

Comment: Insert the image into `\vtop` with a first element for example `\kern0pt`, then image itself. If the second `\vtop` starts with the same `\kern` followed by the paragraph text then these two `\vtop`s will be aligned vertically with respect to these two kerns.

Comment: after your edit they are aligned as expected, the baseline of the image is aligned with the baseline of the first line of text. If that is not what you want, you need to say what you do want.

Comment: as @wipet says if you want to align on the top of the boxes, not the baseline of the first entry in each box, place a 0 sized kern (or skip or box, or anything) at the start of each of the `vtop`

Comment: That is exactly it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide any example of your input or resulting mis-alignment, but latex's `\includegraphics` for example always places the baseline on the bottom edge of the image so acts like the `\vrule` shown here.

[image]

```
\hbox to \hsize {%don't forget this
    xxxxxxxxx%
    \vtop{\hsize=1cm \noindent\vrule width 1cm height 2cm}%
    \hskip1cm
    \vtop{\hsize=1cm \noindent\vrule width 1cm height 4cm }%
    xxxxxxx%
   }

  \bye
```

as you see, the two rules are aligned on their bottom edge, which is aligned with the baseline of the xxx text.

---

after your edit it seems that you want to align the top of the image with the top of the text, the second aligns it with the baseline of the first line of text, the second raises it by the height of a strut, that may be too much, you may want to raise it by just the `ex if most of the text is lowercase.

[image]

```
\hbox to \hsize {%don't forget this
    xxxxxxxxx%
    \vtop{\hsize=1cm \noindent\vrule width 1cm height 2cm}%
    \hskip1cm
    \vtop{\hsize=2cm a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z }%
    xxxxxxx%
  }


  \bigskip\hrule\bigskip

  
\hbox to \hsize {%don't forget this
    xxxxxxxxx%
    \vtop{\kern0pt
      \hsize=1cm \noindent\vrule width 1cm height 2cm}%
    \hskip1cm
    \vtop{\hsize=2cm
      \noindent\strut a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z }%
    xxxxxxx%
  }


  
  \bigskip\hrule\bigskip

  
\hbox to \hsize {%don't forget this
    xxxxxxxxx%
    \vtop{\kern-\ht\strutbox
      \hsize=1cm \noindent\vrule width 1cm height 2cm}%
    \hskip1cm
    \vtop{\hsize=2cm
      \noindent\strut a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z }%
    xxxxxxx%
   }

  \bye
```